# Renaming a question or asking a similar one and risk duplicate flag

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I asked this [Betweenness centrality with listS, illegal use of type 'void' in adjacency_list.hpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263594/betweenness-centrality-with-lists-illegal-use-of-type-void-in-adjacency-list). I still do not understand the error I'm getting but I allude to a question at the end about adding a vertex descriptor on the fly. That is the question that I'm interested in really.

My question for Meta is should I rename this question to get at my real issue or should I ask a new question? I'm afraid that asking the new question might get flagged as a duplicate. Renaming the question might prevent getting a good answer due to staleness.

Comment: Looking at the question you linked, it's entirely unclear what you're actually asking. I think editing it is a good idea; trim a lot of the code, and make it more specific what you're really asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since edits bump questions to the top of the list, there's no real reason not to edit to clarify what you're trying to get at. There are no answers to invalidate, either. Edit your question so that it asks what you intended in the first place, or what you should have intended, as the case may be.

You can also add a bounty if the simple bumping proves insufficient, of course.

Asking a new question that is, at the core, the same one, *will* deserve duplicate closing, and will hopefully get it.

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question a duplicate? Does the old question have an answer that solves your problem? Read all the answers.

If the existing question doesn't already have an existing answer to your question, it sounds like these questions are not duplicates. To be certain yours is not closed as a duplicate, be sure you include a link to the previous question and explain you've tried the solutions offered there and explained why they have not worked for you. Additionally, describe any details that will help distinguish your problem from the original problem.

Comment: Just because the answers on the original question don't solve your problem doesn't necessarily mean that the question is not still a duplicate.  I've seen people claim their question is not a dupe because the only way they can solve their problem is by making modifications to the source (answers in the original question) and they just don't feel like doing that.

Answer (score -11):

**Ask a new question**, and in your new question **description** on line **1** mention `you didn't want to have that Question Title`.

So in turn, your Question will be **New** and It **won't be closed** as you stated already about question title.

Comment: A different title a distinct question does not make. And anyway, if a duplicate question is linked, it will be closed for that: The critcal part is making it different, and the link is for showing your research so there's no needless duplication.